# Efeito slideToggle() para abrir na horizontal + JQuery (menu horizontal)

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="assets/img/apple-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />    

<title>Admin GUSTAVO</title>

<!-- JS on-line --> 
<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    

<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.0.2/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- ================================================= -->    
<!-- CSS Bloco - Referente ao Editor bootstrap-wysiwyg -->
<!-- ================================================= -->    

<!-- JS external -->
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-wysiwyg/js/external/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>

<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-wysiwyg/js/external/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>

<!-- JS editor -->    

<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-wysiwyg/js/bootstrap-wysiwyg.js"></script>

<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-wysiwyg/js/ferramentas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

<!-- CSS editor -->

<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-wysiwyg/css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-wysiwyg/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  

<!-- ================================================= -->    
<!-- CSS Bloco - Referente ao Editor bootstrap-wysiwyg -->
<!-- ================================================= -->    

<!-- JS Jquery -->
<!--<script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--> 

<!-- Core CSS -->    
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Personalizações CSS -->  
<link href="../assets/css/personalizado.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Dashborad Painel CSS -->  
<link href="../assets/css/dashborad-painel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    



<!-- ================================================ -->    
<!-- JS e CSS Bloco - Referente ao efeito de fancybox -->
<!-- ================================================ -->    

<!-- Add jQuery library --><!-- JS ocultar e apresentar -->
<!--<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>-->

<!-- biblioteca on-line -->
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel.pack.js?v=3.1.3"></script>-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel.pack.js?v=3.1.3"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>


<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

<!-- ================================================ -->    
<!-- JS e CSS Bloco - Referente ao efeito de fancybox -->
<!-- ================================================ -->    



<script type="text/javascript">

    /* ================================================================= */
    /* converte o conteúdo da DIV em textarea e envia os dados via PSOT */
    /* =============================================================== */    

    $('#btn-enviar').click(function(){
        //trata o conteudo vindo da Div e o transfere para um textarea que fica ocluto.
        $("#redacao").text($("#editor").html());
        //ativa a ação após dar o click no botão de enviar
        $('#form_redacao').submit();    
    });        

    /* =============================================================== */    
                /* efeito de ocultar listagem de produtos */
    /* =============================================================== */    
    /* efeito de listagem de produtos */    
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#revelar").click(function(){
                /*$("#esconder").slideToggle("slow");*/
                $("#esconder").animate({width: 'toggle'});
                /*$("#ocultar").css('display', 'none');*/
            });
        });

        /* efeito de silde com icone  */    
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#slideleft button').click(function () {
               $(this).toggleClass('aberto').next().toggleClass('aberto');
            });
        });    



    /* =============================================================== */    
                    /* efeito de galeria de imagens */
    /* =============================================================== */    
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();
        });      

    /* =============================================================== */    
    /* Alterar o tipo de título, velocidade sobreposição de encerramento */
    /* =============================================================== */    
        $("#fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title : {
                 type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0
                }
            }
        });

</script>     

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>               
            </div>            
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Perfil</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Configurações</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sair</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!--<div class="row">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar...">
            </form> 
        </div>-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sidebar" id="esconder">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="menu-collapse">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMenu">
                          Home
                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseMenu">

                            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="?paginas=index" title="Home">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="?paginas=noticia" title="noticia">Notícias</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="?paginas=slide" title="slide">Slide</a>
                                </li>                                
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="?paginas=editor" title="editor">Editor</a>
                                </li>                             
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <a id="revelar" class="btn btn-default" href="#">Exibir Menu</a>
                <?php include_once("paginas.php")?>
                <!--<p>teste de conteúdo</p>-->
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>    

</body>
    <!-- JS Core -->

    <!--<script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/npm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>-->

    <!-- JS Plugn's Bootstrap -->
    <script src="../assets/js/collapse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/tab.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/popover.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/scrollspy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/alert.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/affix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/transition.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

estou precisando de uma ajudinha aqui... estou criando um painel admin do zero.., a nível de adquirir conhecimento, estudo, etc.. até o momento consegui um efeito parecido usando o slideToggle porem estou querendo que ele abra na horizontal...  a ideia é criar um sidebar, atualmente está de baixo para cima.. segue código criado até agora, dei uma rezumida poais o mesmo é grande..

abaixo temos as chamadas de css e js principais

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

aqui fica a função que executa o efeito slidetoggle:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#revelar").click(function(){
                $("#esconder").slideToggle("slow");
                /*$("#ocultar").css('display', 'none');*/
            });
        });
</script>
```

e por fim o html do painel no qual o efeito é executado.

```
<html>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>               
            </div>            
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Perfil</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Configurações</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sair</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!--<div class="row">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar...">
            </form> 
        </div>-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sidebar" id="esconder">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="menu-collapse">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMenu">
                          Home
                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseMenu">

                            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="?paginas=index" title="Home">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="?paginas=noticia" title="noticia">Notícias</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="?paginas=editor" title="editor">Editor</a>
                                </li>                             
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <a id="revelar" class="btn btn-default" href="#">Exibir Menu</a>
                <?php include_once("paginas.php")?>
                <!--<p>teste de conteúdo</p>-->
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>    

</body>
    <!-- JS Core -->

    <!--<script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/npm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>-->

    <!-- JS Plugn's Bootstrap -->
    <script src="../assets/js/collapse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/tab.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/popover.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/scrollspy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/alert.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/affix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/transition.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Desde já agradeço a todos pela atenção ! se precisarem de mais alguma informação, estarei as ordens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os efeitos de slide do jQuery só são aplicados no `height` do elemento, ou seja, verticalmente. Para usar o mesmo efeito horizontalmente, utilize o `animate` com `width: 'toggle'`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#revelar").click(function(){
       $("#esconder").animate({width: 'toggle'});
       /*$("#ocultar").css('display', 'none');*/
   });
});
```

```css
#esconder{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>               
      </div>            
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
              <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Perfil</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Configurações</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sair</a></li>
          </ul>

      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!--<div class="row">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar...">
      </form> 
  </div>-->
  <div class="row">
      <div class="sidebar" id="esconder">
          <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="menu-collapse">
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMenu">
                    Home
                  </a>
                  <div class="collapse" id="collapseMenu">

                      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                          <li class="active">
                              <a href="?paginas=index" title="Home">Home</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="active">
                              <a href="?paginas=noticia" title="noticia">Notícias</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="active">
                              <a href="?paginas=editor" title="editor">Editor</a>
                          </li>                             
                      </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>                  
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
          <a id="revelar" class="btn btn-default" href="#">Exibir Menu</a>
          <!--<p>teste de conteúdo</p>-->
      </div>
  </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Sam, eu fiz a mudança na linha do JS e fiz a inclusão do CSS, porem o que ocorre é que ele faz o efeito mais ao final ele também mantei a passagem de baixo para cima e ambos perdem a suavização no movimento

Comment: O problema é que com esse código da pergunta não tem como reproduzir a página corretamente o menu. Execute o código da minha resposta em tela cheia e vc vai ver que o menu desliza para os lados de forma suave.

Comment: Entendo, vou por ele completo no topo do post para ver se ajuda ! e vc tb vai poder ver o efeito como está.

Comment: o que está ocorrendo é que a versão do bootstrap que estou usando é a v3.4 e a sua é a 4 está provocando algum conflito...